# Use Satellite repositories during podman build on RHEL8

Tags: repo, podman, satellite, rhel8, ubi

I need to be able to use my company's satellite repository while building podman image on top of Red Hat 8 UBI image. I was able to achieve that by copying from host machine those files:
/etc/yum.repos.d ,/etc/rhsm and/etc/pki
to image during build, however it doesn't seem to be elegant solution.

Is there any way to tell podman to use Host machine entitlements/yum repos during docker build ?